# Generating a big range of numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do I generate a range of numbers in one column in MySQL? I'm looking for any soluton to make numbers range that starts from 500000000 and ends on 889999999.

Comment: which mysql version are you using

Comment: SQL is for the storage and retrieval of relational data, and not much else

Comment: What do you mean by make numbers range?  Store it in a table?  Use it in a query, as a constraint?  Or to left join some table?  Show how you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that may want to use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the column value you want. You can set the starting value to the one you desire in this way.

Also, you can only have one `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in a given table.

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
    column_1 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT = 500000000
    --Add other columns
)
```

If you already have a table with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, just set the value to the one you want.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 500000000;
```

If what you want is to insert rows with those numbers, use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, generate the range in a text file, by any means available.
Unload to a text file.
Load that text file to your table. You don not say if you are constrained by how long this takes. It sounds like you just want a table of a single column of INT with lower and upper limits.

MySQL should just handle these numbers,this is not really a "big" range, seriously.

- Do you want to constrain the values in the column to
  {500000000..889999999}?
- Or do you want to know how to define a column
  to hold these values?
- Do you want a written procedure to generate
  these numbers for you?
- Do you want us to size this for you?
- Do you want us to write a script or program to load these?

All of these answers are available with minimal sweat. Keywords are MySQL,Integer, Types.

We cannot see your problem because your question does not describe a problem.

Tell us what you tried, and tell us what happened...

Otherwise just add them, you are still in INT territory (-2Gi..2Gi), not BIGINT yet.

Comment: question belong into comments

Answer (score 0):

Switch to MariaDB, then `JOIN` to a pseudo-table called `seq_500000000_to_889999999`.